# How to check png file if it's a decompression bomb

Tags: security, image-processing, imagemagick, png

I am playing with image uploads to a website and I found out about these decompression bomb attacks that can take place when it's allowed to upload `png` files (and some other). Since I am going to change the uploaded images, I want to make sure I don't become a victim of this attack. So when it comes to checking if a `png` file is a bomb, can I just read the file's headers and make sure that width and height are not more than the set limit, like 4000x4000 or whatever? Is it a valid method? Or what is the better way to go?

Comment: You should do it at the web server layer. What are you using to host your site?

Comment: Glenn Randers-Pehrson describes a number of defensive strategies in [Defending Libpng Applications Against Decompression Bombs](http://libpng.sourceforge.net/decompression_bombs.html), but the article supposes you are compiling your own software with `libpng`. Still worth a read, though.

Comment: @Jongware I have read it, but I am not using anything of what is mentioned there.  I simply need a way to make sure that the uploaded file is not a bomb using my backend language if it's possible of course

Comment: Your "imagemagick" tag indicates that you are you asking how to do it with ImageMagick.  Are you using your own copy of ImageMagick, or are you relying on one that someone else has built and installed?

Comment: I'd have to go over my own decompression routines to cross-check, but I believe just checking the width and height may not be enough. What if I create such a giga-png (compressed!) and then hack its width and height to lower values? Then it's up to the actual decompression routine to keep memory use in check.

Comment: @Jongware Correct, just width and height is not enough. There can also be excessively large iCCP chunks, zTXt, chunks, and iTXt chunks.  By default, libpng defends against those to some degree.  Image width and height limits in ImageMagick come from the commandline "-limit" option, which I suppose can also be conveyed via the various ImageMagick APIs.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I will probably just install the most recent stable version of ImageMagick on my vps.

Comment: Yeah, I thought too that it was probably not that hard to forge those width and height headers. So what do I do then? Should I do all that stuff with Libpng mentioned in the article?

Comment: ImageMagick's default limits are very large: "convert -list resource" says
Resource limits:
  Width: 214.7MP
  Height: 214.7MP
  Area: 8.135GP, so you'l need to use the -limit option or its equivalent.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson Understood, thank you very much. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Besides large width and height, decompression bombs can also have excessively large iCCP chunks, zTXt, chunks, and iTXt chunks. By default, libpng defends against those to some degree.

Your "imagemagick" tag indicates that you are you asking how to do it with ImageMagick. ImageMagick's default width and height limits are very large: "convert -list resource" says

> Resource limits: Width: 214.7MP Height: 214.7MP Area: 8.135GP

Image width and height limits in ImageMagick come from the commandline "-limit" option, which I suppose can also be conveyed via some equivalent directive in the various ImageMagick APIs. ImageMagick inherits the limits on iCCP chunks, etc., from libpng.

Forged smaller width and height values in the IHDR chunk don't fool either libpng or ImageMagick.  They just issue an "Extra compressed data" warning and skip the remainder of the IDAT data without decompressing it.