# php gd protection against image decompression bomb

Tags: php, nginx, gd

Imagine a [zip bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb), but in PNG flavour.

When doing any kind of image manipulation in gd it's almost inevitable that at some point the image is held entirely in memory in decompressed form via `imagecreatefromjpeg` and friends even for simple operations like resizing.
`getimagesize` only extracts info from the metadata which can be unreliable.

What tools do we have to protect ourselves from such kinds of abuse, for example in the case of scaling down an image to create a thumbnail?

I thought about:

- Making the server only accept uncompressed BMP or TIFF images and setting mere upload size limitations, with a client-side javascript that would convert jpg and png files to bmp before sending. Very bad for performance in general.
- Actively reducing the available memory for the script in charge of doing the manipulation so that it would fail with an out-of-memory error if the image turns out to be too large (like 16 MB max memory). Bad on a whole new level of bad.

Do `imagescale` and similar functions need the original image to exist in memory decompressed?

Any other tips?

Comment: You can check the extension, mimetype, exif_imagetype, filesize, dimensions, etc. Use imagemagick with a limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602308/how-to-check-png-file-if-its-a-decompression-bomb Resize images on client size with javascript https://davidwalsh.name/image-php-xhtml

Comment: @peixotorms I'll take a look at imagemagick, but i would like to know about some workarounds for GD first if possible.

Comment: Apart from all the methods I referred above, you could clean the uploaded image first via PunyPNG, TinyPNG or any other image optimizer. If you want to protect your server, there are many api's online that can resize and optimize the images for you.

Comment: @peixotorms following the philosophy of _never trust user input_ I cannot rely on client-side javascript nor functions that only read metadata, which can be tampered with. The two services that you mention will optimize the image, not rescale it. The ideal solution would be having a php function that guesses the calculated resolution of the image without using metadata and without decompressing the image fully.